# toggle WP (7 ~ 7.8) user Ring Tone (Ring/vibrate)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Is any way to access the current tone and toggle between tone/vibrate on Custom APP?
Some like

```
...
if isVibrate then
    ChangeToTone()
Else
    ChangeToVibrate()
End if

isVibrate = Not isVibrate
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No! The current SDK for windows phone does not give you access to this. Hopefully we might get it in a future release.